# Extension of USA B2 visa 2nd time

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas, visa-extensions

1. I am in the USA  on a B2 tourism visa. I applied and paid for an extension which is still pending, though I got this note from USCIS:  On January 8, 2021, we scheduled you for a biometrics appointment and sent you an appointment notice for Receipt Number -----. Please follow the instructions in the notice. If you do not receive your appointment notice by February 7, 2021, please go to [www.uscis.gov/e-request](http://www.uscis.gov/e-request) to request a copy of the notice.
2. do I need to file for a second extension or not?
3. How would I file for a second B2 visa extension? Can it be post-dated? How long for are the extensions granted? Thank you, community!

---

My initial B2 Visa expired May 16th 2020, I filed and paid for extension of Visa on May 6th 2020 with I-539 form. About biometrics, They wrote On January 8, 2021, and asked if no letter arrives by Feb 7th 2021 I should contact a certain office to which there is a link on the form.

Comment: What date does your B2 status expire? What date did you apply for the extension? What is the date to give your biometrics?

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to apply again for new extension for visa B2 due to covid?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/156543/19400)

Comment: In addition to the questions asked by @DavidSupportsMonica, it's not possible to answer whether you need to apply for a second extension without knowing when you intend to leave the US.  The extensions are typically granted for six months, though they may be shorter.

Comment: Hi. I've edited your title and added the `b1-b2-visa` tag. If you don't want these changes, feel free to undo them. If you are happy with them, then you don't need to do anything

Comment: Please Xanta, do edit the question instead of adding an answer and do not add 'niceties' which are not relevant to the question, (like thanks and bless).

Comment: Your chances of getting a new visa application refused when you apply for a new B visa is almost guaranteed. Two extensions and staying beyond a year? When flights already commenced months ago? Good luck!